# Error while Displaying data from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the result of an SQL query in an array.
[image]

I have some issues in displaying them in PHP. My code:

```
    $query = ****;

$row = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($row > 0) {          
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $awardname = trim($result['awardname']);
        $name = trim($result['preferred_name']).' '.trim($result['surname']);

        $arr = array();
        $array[$awardname] = $name;
    }

        foreach($array as $awardname => $names ){
            echo $awardname. ' given to:  <br />';
            foreach($names as $name){
                echo  $name;
            }
        }       
}
```

All I am trying to do is to display the Awards and the name of the recipients underneath them (one name beside or below the other)
The error I am receiving is:
[image]

Line 32:  `foreach($names as $name){`

Can any of you suggest what is incorrect?

Comment: you dont need that 2nd loop

Comment: Seems like a typo question.  You should have dumped your array and had a look before posting this question.  Not much value to future readers.  You're not building the `$array` properly.  dump it and see.  `$array[$awardname][]= $name;`  Please delete this question.  Not answering this one.

Comment: Hi Nogad, if I remove the second loop and echo the $name it only shows one name (the last name) for every award.

Comment: @sansam now you may delete while there are no answers posted and regain your rep points.  The `[]` that I have added to your `$array` declaration will fix the element overwriting that you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks mickmackusa

Comment: Please delete your question now.

Comment: at least the low rep users are not being rude  @mickmackusa

Comment: Just trying to keep SO clean and spare volunteers wasting time in review queues. I even said "please". Question deletion also benefits the OP.  Looks like sansam has gone away @nogad please vote to close.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for all the support that I have received through this forum. I  really do not understand the significance of scores and badges or whatever is important in here. All I can say is: I have tried several combinations and read the answers to several similar questions, but was unable to resolve the issue. I am not a professional programmer. If it is very important to have high scores, in order to ask a question then it will become difficult for people like me who just love to write some codes, to search for a solution. Thanks again.. :)

Comment: Hi @sansam please write echo "<pre>";print_r($array); after while loop and paste the result here. After that I can help you...

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add `[]` to your array declaration.  Here are a few more refinements:

```
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $array[trim($result['awardname'])][]=trim($result['preferred_name']).' '.trim($result['surname']);
}

foreach($array as $awardname=>$names){
    echo $awardname,' given to:  <br />',implode(', ',$names),'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Hi mickmackusa, I was able to resolve the issue from your first clue. Thanks   a lot... :)

Comment: I don't mean to be rude here. this question will be delete eventually.  Please remove the green tick. so that I can delete the answer and you can delete your question.

Comment: I am trying to help you regain lost rep points.  This also spares moderation time.

Comment: Oh well it will get mopped up eventually.